# Getting a derived attribute through two different tables

Tags: database, postgresql

I need to get the salary of an employee through two different tables: his gains and his discounts. The relation from the table employee to the two tables is a many to many relation. So I need to take the employee_id, get all the gain_id in the employee_gains table, add all of them and subtract with the analogue result in the discounts.

I tried this creating a view for the salary:

```
  CREATE VIEW salary as 
select ((select sum(value) from gains 
where gain_id in (select gain_id from gain_employee where employee_id=2)) 
- 
(select sum(value) from discount 
where discount_id in (select gain_id from discount_employee where employee_id=2)));
```

However, this only (and successfully) gives me the salary for the employee with ID 2. But how can I make this generic? I want a view salary for all the employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use two CTEs to calculate the gains and discounts and then do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on the two sets. This will ensure that you get proper values such as 0 for missing gains or discounts for an employee_id. If you want to ignore them such cases just change it to a plain `INNER JOIN`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_salary AS  --give proper name to indicate it's a view 
WITH ge 
     AS (SELECT e.employee_id, 
                SUM(g.value) AS gain_value 
         FROM   gain_employee e 
                JOIN gains g --use left join if some employees don't 
                             --have an entry in gains
                  ON e.gain_id = g.gain_id 
         GROUP  BY e.employee_id), 
     de 
     AS (SELECT e.employee_id, 
                SUM(d.value) AS dis_value
         FROM   discount_employee e  
                JOIN discounts d --use left join if some employees don't 
                                 --have an entry in discount
                 ON  e.discount_id = d.discount_id 
         GROUP  BY e.employee_id) 
SELECT COALESCE(ge.employee_id, gd.employee_id), --gets you atleast one of 
                                                 --them when one may be missing. 
       COALESCE(ge.gain_value, 0) - COALESCE(de.dis_value, 0) AS salary 
FROM   ge 
       FULL OUTER JOIN de    -- to consider case where one of them is absent
                    ON ge.employee_id = de.employee_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it -

```
CREATE VIEW salary as
select S1.employee_id, (S1.gains - S2.discounts) as salary
    from (select ge.employee_id, sum(g.value) as gains 
              from gain_employee ge, gains g
              where ge.gain_id = g.gain_id
              group by ge.employee_id) S1,
         (select de.employee_id, sum(d.value) as discounts 
              from discount_employee de, discounts d
              where de.doscount_id = d.discount_id
              group by de.employee_id) S2
    where S1.employee_id = S2.employee_id;
```

Then you can query this view with `employee_id` as the condition.